# How to delete IFTTT account?

Tags: if-this-then-that

How can I permanently delete my account at IFTTT ?

I could not find any help on the site, nor any information on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [help](https://ifttt.com/help) page make it clear:

> How do I delete my IFTTT account?
>   Please contact support@ifttt.com with your IFTTT username.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a link to the help page anywhere

Comment: The link to the help page was present on the contact page, btw.

Comment: The text on the help page has been changed. They now offer a form for self-service deactivation.

Answer (score 7):

At the bottom of the [settings](https://ifttt.com/settings) page there is a link: [I’d like to deactivate my account](https://ifttt.com/settings/deactivate). (You can get to the settings page by clicking your account name in the upper right corner then choosing "Settings".)

They note on the [subsequent page](https://ifttt.com/settings/deactivate) that

> Deactivating your IFTTT account is permanent and cannot be undone.

Enter your password to complete the process. They also ask you to tell them why you're leaving.

---

Also, the [Help](https://ifttt.com/help) page (accessible via the [Contact](https://ifttt.com/contact) page) says:

> **How do I deactivate my IFTTT account?**
>
> Visit your [Settings](https://ifttt.com/settings) and click “I’d like to deactivate my account” to begin the deactivation process.

Answer (score 1):

Click *Preferences* from top-right drop down in the account setting tab and you will find the  deactivate option. It is only for deactivating your account, not for deleting it.